# Prove $f$ is $0$ at point of continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be Riemann integrable such that $\int_a^b x^nf(x) \ dx =0,\forall n\geq 0$. Show that if $x_0$ is a point of continuity for $f$ then $f(x_0)=0$.

I understand that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then we can approximate $f$ using polynomials and thus bound $\int_a^b f(x)f(x)\ dx$ because $\forall m\in \mathbb{N},\exists P_m,|\int_a^b f(x)f(x)\ dx| = |\int_a^b f(x)f(x)\ dx-\int_a^b P_m(x)f(x)\ dx|<\frac{1}{m}\int_a^b f(x)\ dx$.

However, here $f$ is only continuous at a point $x_0$. How can I modify the argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: suppose $f(x_0) >0$. There exists $\epsilon >0$ and an interval $I=(x_0- \epsilon, x_0+ \epsilon)$ around $x_0$ such that $f(x) \geq \epsilon$ for all $x \in I$. Construct a continuous function $g_n$ with values in $[0,1]$   such that $g_n=1$ on $(x_0- \epsilon, x_0+ \epsilon)$  and $0$ for points outside the interval $(x_0- \epsilon-\frac  1 n, x_0+ \epsilon+\frac 1 n)$. Now take limits in the equation $\int f (x)g_n(x)dx=0$ to see that $\int_I f(x)dx=0$. This leads to a contradiction.

Comment: If we want to take limit at the last step, shouldn't we require $f(x)g_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x)g(x)$ where $g$ is the point-wise limit of $g_n$? But $g_n$ doesn't converge uniformly to $g$ since $g$ is not continuous?

Comment: Uniform convergence is not required. Pointwise convergence and the fact that $0 \leq g_n(x) \leq 1$ is enough.

Comment: Why is that? I only learnt that we can interchange limit and integral if the integrand converges uniformly.

Comment: $\int_{(x_0+\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon+\frac 1 n)}  |fg_n-f| \leq M\frac 1 n$ where $M=sup |f(x)|$. Similarly you can handle the integral over $(x_0+\epsilon-\frac 1 n,x_0+\epsilon)$.

Comment: I see. Is there a general statement about this kind of convergence?

Comment: I am not applying any standard theorem, just doing it from first principles.